# Facebook Android Release hash key

Tags: android, facebook, hash

I have no problem login with facebook using Development key and running debug apk.
But when I generate release apk and run on the device, it shows

"Invalid key has, the key hash xxxxxxxxxx does not match any stored key hashes"

I actually added the release key on console, and that key does not match the key above, even I typed the key shown above, it does not work,
I used the following command to generate release key:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\ywj7931\.android\debug.keystore | C:\Users\ywj7931\Downloads\openssl-0.9.8e_X64\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\Users\ywj7931\Downloads\openssl-0.9.8e_X64\bin\openssl base64
```

Is it because my app is not published on google play or not reviewed by facebook yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get your Production Hash key and add it to your Facebook Hash Keys in Facebook Console.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

After you get the key you can add it in your Facebook App Page.

or you can get it like below in the prod apk which you signed with your Production Key store.

```
try {
         PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
         "com.app.package",
         PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
         for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
         MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
         md.update(signature.toByteArray());
         Log.d("KeyHash", "KeyHash:"+ Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),
         Base64.DEFAULT));
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),
                 Base64.DEFAULT), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
         } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

         } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

         }
```

After you get you have to add it to your hash keys in your App Page in Facebook Console.

Comment: I think the first command is exactly the same as mine used, but still does not work

Comment: in your production apk which you signed with key, you can try second solution and log your key. then you can add it to Facebook console and remove this log and operation from your apk.

Comment: Well, it still doesn't work, is it because my app hasn't published on google play? For the first solution, I am using the key I signed my apk, is that correct?

Comment: Yes you have to send your apk to Facebook and verify it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are key hash doesn't match on your stored key hash on Facebook. you can see the log key hash using this code :

```
Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Add code to print out the key hash
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

And then copy and paste this Release Key Hash into your Facebook App ID's Android settings.

**Update**
if you want to be add it manually you can add the key hash from error in your application and then type it manually  your  Facebook App ID's Android settings. this work for me but pain to type the correct one and also dont forget to add `~` or any character which displayed from invalid key hash.

Comment: This should be development key and I have copied and paste it to my console, and it still does not work

Comment: @ywj7931 you can also type it manually, but painful when type it.